# Android Socket Stream

Tags: java, android, sockets

In my app I'm using socket connection to communicate with a server. Everything works fine, I'm able to send/receive from/to the server with no issues. None, but one. There's a certain option/response from the server than leaves the connection open for around 30 seconds. Server sends the reply right away, but it keeps the connection open and as such the app hangs there showing the 'waiting' message, because I can't seem to figure out how to close the connection/inputStream without it waiting for the server to close it.

Is there a way to read each character received by the buffer and as soon as a character is found ('*' for example) the buffer should close and also the connection to the server.

Any help?

Comment: you can use http way to do that. one of feature of http is sending length of stream before sending actual data. so, your app can know how many bytes will be transferred. but, I dont understand why you dont compare every received byte one by one

Comment: Adem, I cant use http (believe me, I would if i could) since I'm not responsible for the "server" side and, so, I've to work with what I'm given :| . What you mean by comparing each byte?

Comment: I did not say use http, I propose just handle it like http. you can take a look http chunked (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). check out my answer for comparing each byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to manage it between client and server. One approach is HTTP chunked. HTTP chunked send first length of message, then message data. Or, if as it is your case, if you know a "magic" byte notifies client that connection can close, you can read data one by one, and when you reach the finalizer byte, you can complete your reading and close connection. Otherwise, application hangs in `input.read()` until connection reaches timeout or new byte arrives

```
InputStream input = ....;
ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while (true){
   int singlebyte = input.read();
   if (singlebyte == -1) break; //stream ends
    bo.write(singlebyte);
    if (singlebyte == '*'){
       //the byte you are wating. at this point, you can break loop. or continue to read
       bo.write(singlebyte);
       byte data[] = bo.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not use code only answers. The question also indicated that the connection to the server was to be closed.

Comment: Adem, you are a life-saver! I stumbled with this about 9 months ago (back when I was too much of a newbie with Android to even figure this out) and just recently decided to try and fix it. Thanks to you, I did! Thank you so much..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You *do* 'read each character as it is found'. Your problem here is not reading characters, it is the server not closing the connection, so you're blocked waiting for end of stream. Such a protocol is either broken, in which case it needs redesigning, or else it includes a length indicator or some other means of knowing when the message is complete,mwhich you're not taking proper notice of.